# Running elastic search integration test throwing an exception?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Hi I am having a spring boot application that uses cassandra as the database. Recently i got a requirement to support elastic search in the application . so i have created a class AbstractElasticSearchTest that will start an embedded elastic search instance. I have written a small junit test however running it throws exception related to cassandra.

so following is my base AbstractElasticSearchTest class.

```
@ActiveProfiles(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_TEST)
public class AbstractElasticSearchTest {

    private static EmbeddedElastic embeddedElastic;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startElasticServer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        embeddedElastic = EmbeddedElastic.builder().withElasticVersion("6.6.1")
                .withSetting(PopularProperties.TRANSPORT_TCP_PORT, 9350)
                .withSetting(PopularProperties.CLUSTER_NAME, "my_cluster")
                .withStartTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                  .withIndex("cars", IndexSettings.builder()
                            .withType("car", getSystemResourceAsStream())
                            .build())
                .build()
                .start();

    }

    private static InputStream getSystemResourceAsStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("config/elasticsearch/car-mapping.json");
        return is;
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void close() {
        embeddedElastic.stop();
    }   
}
```

the junit integration test is as follow.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PrimecastApp.class)
public class PerformanceReportingIntTest extends AbstractElasticSearchTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }   

}
```

The exception that i recieves is below.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'assigningAccountAspect' defined in file [/Users/kannan/mep/api/target/classes/com/openmind/primecast/aop/assigning/AssigningAccountAspect.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in file [/Users/kannan/mep/api/target/classes/com/openmind/primecast/repository/UserRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/openmind/primecast/config/CassandraTestConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'session' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cluster' defined in class path resource [com/openmind/primecast/config/CassandraTestConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: Factory method 'cluster' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in file [/Users/kannan/mep/api/target/classes/com/openmind/primecast/repository/UserRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/openmind/primecast/config/CassandraTestConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'session' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cluster' defined in class path resource [com/openmind/primecast/config/CassandraTestConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: Factory method 'cluster' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/openmind/primecast/config/CassandraTestConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'session' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cluster' defined in class path resource [com/openmind/primecast/config/CassandraTestConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: Factory method 'cluster' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cluster' defined in class path resource [com/openmind/primecast/config/CassandraTestConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: Factory method 'cluster' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: Factory method 'cluster' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getNativeTransportPort(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1737)
    at com.openmind.primecast.config.CassandraTestConfiguration.getPort(CassandraTestConfiguration.java:33)
    at com.openmind.primecast.config.cassandra.CassandraConfiguration.cluster(CassandraConfiguration.java:44)
    at com.openmind.primecast.config.CassandraTestConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$87e39ac1.CGLIB$cluster$2(<generated>)
    at com.openmind.primecast.config.CassandraTestConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$87e39ac1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c3451509.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.openmind.primecast.config.CassandraTestConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$87e39ac1.cluster(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 87 more
```

i think it is more related to spring boot configuration . appreciate if you can throw any insight into it .

[ I am sharing the code in git hub
git clone https://github.com/prasanthmp500/mep.git
please checkout the branch ENG-170-performance-reports and run mvn clean test under api folder . ]

i have a cassandra embedded instance that is run from a class

```
/**
 * Base class for starting/stopping Cassandra during tests.
 */
@ActiveProfiles(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_TEST)
public class AbstractCassandraTest {

    public static final String CASSANDRA_UNIT_KEYSPACE = "cassandra_unit_keyspace";
    private static final String CASSANDRA_UNIT_RANDOM_PORT_YAML = "cassandra-random-port.yml";
    public static final String CQL_DIR = "config/cql/changelog/";
    // Not adding the changelog directory as when loading the resources this is then the default directory and it's preferable to
    // load all data from the "config/cql/changelog/" first before looking to the test resources.
    public static final String TEST_CQL_DIR = "config/cql/";
    private static final long CASSANDRA_TIMEOUT = 30000L;
    private static boolean started = false;
    private static Session session;
    private static CQLDataLoader dataLoader;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startServer() throws TTransportException, ConfigurationException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
        if (!started) {
            EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(CASSANDRA_UNIT_RANDOM_PORT_YAML, CASSANDRA_TIMEOUT);
            Cluster cluster = new Cluster.Builder().addContactPoints("127.0.0.1").withPort(getNativeTransportPort())
                .build();
            session = cluster.connect();
            String createQuery = "CREATE KEYSPACE " + CASSANDRA_UNIT_KEYSPACE + " WITH replication={'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1}";
            session.execute(createQuery);
            String useKeyspaceQuery = "USE " + CASSANDRA_UNIT_KEYSPACE;
            session.execute(useKeyspaceQuery);
            dataLoader = new CQLDataLoader(session);
            applyScripts(dataLoader, CQL_DIR, "*.cql");
            started = true;
        }
    }

    public static void applyScript(String dir, String cql) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        applyScripts(dataLoader, dir, cql);
    }

    private static void applyScripts(CQLDataLoader dataLoader, String cqlDir, String pattern) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        URL dirUrl = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(cqlDir);
        if (dirUrl == null) { // protect for empty directory
            return;
        }

        List<String> scripts = new ArrayList<>();
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(dirUrl.toURI()), pattern)) {
            for (Path entry : stream) {
                scripts.add(entry.getFileName().toString());
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(scripts);

        for (String fileName : scripts) {
            dataLoader.load(new ClassPathCQLDataSet(cqlDir + fileName, false, false, CASSANDRA_UNIT_KEYSPACE));
        }
    }
}
```

so most of my tests run extends like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PrimecastApp.class)
public class AccountResourceIntTest extends AbstractCassandraTest {

}
```

so probably i should rewrite this class  PerformanceReportingIntTest to extend AbstractCassandraTest and inject an instance of AbstractElasticSearchTest into the PerformanceReportingIntTest. not sure if i am going in the right direction.

thank you

Comment: So the casandra Driver is throwing a NULL pointer so safe bet the connection config details are not getting to it for some reason.   Are you running Casandra for the test in a Test Container?

Comment: Hi Brian that is right connection config details are not getting for some reason . yes in other integration tests i am creating an instance of embedded cassandra .

Comment: Ok, so if it is a test container how are you setting the dynamically created connection values?

Comment: AbstractCassandraTest , i have just attached this class in the description . this class is extended by all integration junit tests . this creates an instance of cassandra process

Comment: Right but that is not setting the Spring properties so all the Spring Boot auto configure stuff knows how to connect.

Comment: so brian where can i check it ? or maybe i didnt understand the question . https://github.com/prasanthmp500/mep.git i have a created a branch ENG-170-performance-reports . will you able to figure it out ? thank you ..really sorry for my bad knowledge. thank you

Comment: Ok since you are asking where I am taking that to mean those values were never set.   You can Google SpringBoot casandra connection properties to get the property stirng names.   Then need to set the values for this Casandra instnace.